# GoogleAnalytics for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-analytics

I been trying to add google analytics to my xamarin forms apps , but everything I see contains a lot of code, is there any easy way to get this working.It cant be this hard. 
I followed this https://github.com/KSemenenko/GoogleAnalyticsForXamarinForms , but when I added the init part it cant find the namespace. the nuget is already installed.

what other steps should I follow?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Instead post the code itself and the related error message

Comment: Did you install [ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics/) successfully? And add `using Plugin.GoogleAnalytics;` in your project? I just installed it and the code works well on my side.

Comment: That's the code you find on his Github account.Nothing especial about it

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT can you make it as an answer, it worked,  I had another analytics package and it was conflicting with this one . Plus the namespace of the package was not easy to guess.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics, install [ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics/) package, and add the namespace using `Plugin.GoogleAnalytics;`:

then you can use the api in your porject:

```
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.TrackingId = "UA-11111111-1";
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppId = "AppID";
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppName = "TEST";
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppVersion = "1.0.0.0";
//GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.Debug = true;
//For tracking install and starts app, you can change default event properties:
//GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.ServiceCategoryName = "App";
//GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.InstallMessage = "Install";
//GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.StartMessage = "Start";
//GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppInstallerId = "someID"; // for custom installer id
GoogleAnalytics.Current.InitTracker();

//Track view
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Tracker.SendView("MainPage");
```